# show confirm delete box from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this form to manage an article. In 'action', I select article and choose either approve, archive, or delete. from the select box. Then I click the accept button.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <select class="form-control contentgroup input-sm" name="action" id="action">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="addtoarchive">Archive</option>
        <option value="removefromarchive">approve</option>
        <option value="delete">Delete</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value="240" />Article 1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value="241" />Article 2
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value="242" />Article 3
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedposts[]" class="check" value="243" />Article 4
    <br>
    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
</form>
<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-body">Are you sure?</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added a bootstrap confirm modal bootstrap like this :

```
$('button[name="remove_levels"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirm').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    })
        .one('click', '#delete', function (e) {
        $form.trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

This worked for the accept button, but `Only` after I choose `delete` and select an article from the list, I need to show the confirm modal box.

How can I create this behaviour using jQuery and a bootstrap modal box?

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3ddq/169/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The confirm modal shows but you are trying to show another modal when the '#delete' button is clicked? I do not see this modal.

Comment: @EugeneScray: I need to show the confirm modal box `Only` after choose delete option from select box not for default or choose another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is listen for the select change event.

You could try something like this

```
$('select[name="action"]').on('change', function (e) {
var $form = $(this).closest('form');
var checked = $( "input:checked" ).length;  

e.preventDefault();

if($(this).val()==="delete" && checked) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })
      .one('click', '#delete', function (e) {
       $form.trigger('submit');
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dh0g6cge/

Comment: i cant see modal box after choose delete from select box and click button!

Comment: Did you select at least one checkbox? I'm checking if there's a least one thing selected

Comment: Sure. your code work when user (first) click in article checkbox and then choose delete from select box. this is not good way. I need to show modal box when user choose delete and select article and after click in accept button. my mean is : only when choose delete and select article and click accept show modal box.

Comment: good work with little problem: in default accept button not work for approve and archive action (not send form data). my mean is in your code accept button only work with delete choose and select article and for other action not work!!

Comment: Yep, may be i got your question wrong. But essentially what i am doing, i'm checking if the delete from the select list is selected and that a least one option has been selected from the checkboxes. Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: for approve and archive i dont need to confirm modal box. if user choose delete and checked article modal box show else form worked normal without confirm modal box and send form data.

Comment: Well, in that case just change the location of e.preventDefault() to happen only delete was selected. I made the change here http://jsfiddle.net/1hr1saew/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your after by looking at the comments.

```
$('button[name="remove_levels"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#action").val() == "delete" && $(".check").is(":checked")){
        $('#confirm').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        })
            .one('click', '#delete', function (e) {
            $form.trigger('submit');
        });
    }else{
        //Do Something else if a different "select" option is selected or
        //a checkbox isnt checked        
    }
});
```

The if conditional statement checks to see if the value of the `select` box is "delete" and that one of the `check boxes` is `checked` if both conditions are met then you get the `modal dialog` and i added the `else` as i assume you want to do something else if both conditions are not met.

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/qznmudoh/) showing it in action.

Hope this helps.

Comment: accept button not work for other action. in default accept button not work for approve and archive action (not send form data). my mean is in your code accept button only work with delete choose and select article and for other action not work!!